# How to decompile android kernel within android itself?

Tags: kernel

How do I decompile kernel.bin of my android 4.1.2 kernel on android itself?
Is there an app that can decompile kernel.bin or any methods for decompiling kernel.bin?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want to extract the `.bin` or `.img` file, or do you really mean decompile? Even then, you still need to extract the content before proceeding for anything. [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64628/105083) has the instructions to extract the `boot.img`, in case you need it.

Comment: I know how to extract the kernel but I don't know how to extract the kernel contents to overclock my cpu.

Comment: Here we go. Do you want to overclock CPU to learn something new by decompiling, investing so much of time just for something that can be done without decompiling? Have you heard about UKM, AK kernel/other custom kernels, and Synapse? They can do the overclocking/underclocking without any need to decompile existing kernel. But if you insist for decompiling, then unfortunately I'm out of ideas. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't decompile within android. Not only hardware isn't probably strong enough for compilation/decompilation in most cases, but how do you plan to edit such a huge code in android itself? You will infact need special editors like notepad++ or gedit even in PC to organize the code and be able to understand it to edit. Plus its not "kernel.bin", its " boot.img".

So well, PC is only way for now ;)

Comment: what about a solution for pc?

Comment: @oliver-añasco Decompiling C code is difficult, and you'll likely not end up with usable code at the end. Why do you want to decompile the kernel in the first place?

Comment: @sloosecannon The reason is mentioned in the comments. OP wants to overclock the CPU by decompiling and doing something that will help to overclock. :)